# Why would position: fixed not take an element out of flow?

Tags: html, css, fixed

**Is there any common occurrences of why: `position:fixed` wouldn't take an element out of flow?**  I've never seen this before typically fixed always applies the element to the window.

I have a large applications from which I've applied `position:fixed` to a nested element.  The element is nested because scoped variables. I would link some html and css but nothing seems out of the ordinary? so I really don't know what to display.

*scopeing?* I'm using angular/ui-router and I need the proper controller variables.

**Main.html:**
*This way works when i bring the inner-weekly-categories div out side of ad-container but it messes up my scoping*

```
<div class="inner-weekly-categories-header group">
  <div class="c8-xs c8-sm c8-md product-title">
    <h2>all products</h2>
    <p>results <span>1-{{limitTotal}}</span> of <span>{{categoryProducts.length}}</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="c8-xs c8-sm c8-md category-filter">
    <input type="text" ng-model="dropdownSelected">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ad-container" ui-view="weekly">


</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ad-container {
    z-index: 5;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
inner-weekly-categories-header {
    color: #969696;
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e5e3;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTCom-Roman', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 70px;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 8px 0;
}
```

**The ui-view='weekly' does an xhr request to place** `inner-weeklytegories-header` inside of it.

Comment: Probably best to post some code anyway

Comment: ok give me a moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way for a fixed positioned element not taking the viewport as its boudaries, would be if it's nested to an element that acts as a *stacking context* for fixed elements.

As far as I know, there is at least one situation where it can occur:

**If the element is inside a css transformed element:**

According to [**W3 css transform docs**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#transform), a css element that has a `transform` value, such as `scale`, `rotate`, etc, start acting as a context container for inner fixed elements.

> Any computed value other than none for the transform results in the creation of both a stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as a containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

Comment: that was it.  I ommited a css class by accident and there was a transform3D